# Normalize a list with jsons to a dataframe in steps

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops, for-loop

I have a problem. I have a `list` with `JSONs`. I want to create a complete dataframe in steps. My idea is, for example: My list contains 100 elements. I want to say the size of the steps should be 25. So I say `len(list) / size = 4 = 100 / 25`. I have 4 runs of the for loop and 4 times of concat the small dataframe to the complete. For the MVP I have build a list, with 4 elements and with a step of 2. So every loops it should contactened two elements.

At the end my `dataframe_complete` contains only two rows. What is the problem for that?

The first loop should contain `my_Dict` and `my_Dict2` the second `my_Dict2` and `my_Dict2`. So the list should go from 0-1 and from 2-3. So every loop run should contain two elements.

```py
import pandas as pd

my_Dict = {
'_key': '1',
 'group': 'test',
 'data': {},
 'type': '',
 'code': '007',
 'conType': '1',
 'flag': None,
 'createdAt': '2021',
 'currency': 'EUR',
 'detail': {
        'selector': {
            'number': '12312',
            'isTrue': True,
            'requirements': [{
                'type': 'customer',
                'requirement': '1'}]
            }
        }   
 }

my_Dict2 = {
'_key': '2',
 'group': 'test',
 'data2': {},
 'type': '',
 'code': '007',
 'conType': '1',
 'flag': None,
 'createdAt': '2021',
 'currency': 'EUR',
 'detail2': {
        'selector': {
            'number': '12312',
            'isTrue': True,
            'requirements': [{
                'type': 'customer',
                'requirement': '1'}]
            }
        }   
 }
```

```py
list_dictionaries = [my_Dict, my_Dict2, my_Dict2, my_Dict2]

df_complete = pd.DataFrame()

size= 1
for i in range((len(list_dictionaries) // size)):
    print(i)
    df = pd.json_normalize(list_dictionaries[i], sep='_')
    df_complete= pd.concat([df_complete, df])

print(df_complete)

[OUT]

    _key    group   type    code    conType flag    createdAt   currency    detail_selector_number  detail_selector_isTrue  detail_selector_requirements    detail2_selector_number detail2_selector_isTrue detail2_selector_requirements
0   1   test        007 1   None    2021    EUR 12312   True    [{'type': 'customer', 'requirement': '1'}]  NaN NaN NaN
0   2   test        007 1   None    2021    EUR NaN NaN NaN 12312   True    [{'type': 'customer', 'requirement': '1'}]
```

Expected output

```py
    _key    group   type    code    conType flag    createdAt   currency    detail_selector_number  detail_selector_isTrue  detail_selector_requirements    detail2_selector_number detail2_selector_isTrue detail2_selector_requirements
0   1   test        007 1   None    2021    EUR 12312   True    [{'type': 'customer', 'requirement': '1'}]  NaN NaN NaN
1   2   test        007 1   None    2021    EUR NaN NaN NaN 12312   True    [{'type': 'customer', 'requirement': '1'}]
2   2   test        007 1   None    2021    EUR NaN NaN NaN 12312   True    [{'type': 'customer', 'requirement': '1'}]
3   2   test        007 1   None    2021    EUR NaN NaN NaN 12312   True    [{'type': 'customer', 'requirement': '1'}]
```

Comment: could you please explain why are you using `list_dictionaries[:i]` not `list_dictionaries[i],`

Comment: @FavorMylikes I saw a post how can I get only the first n elements in a list. But I think there is a mistake (?) or is'nt ?

Comment: `[:i]` means: get a list of elements `from first to ith`, `[i]` means the `ith` element

Comment: @FavorMylikes you are right. Sorry. But if I am using `[i]` it also does not work.

Comment: Have you noticed that at the first iteration of df, it gives an empty dataframe or is it so necessary? This is probably due to the fact that in the first iteration list_dictionaries[:i] ---list_dictionaries[:0] .

Comment: @inquirer you are right, thank you. But how could I say first iteration `from` `to` and the second iteration should be `from = to(from the first)+1` `to`

Comment: Thus, you need to do a cycle in steps of two. for i in range(0, len(list_dictionaries), 2).
And at each iteration , refer to two elements list_dictionaries[i+1] and list_dictionaries[i].

Comment: @inquirer thank you very much. Do you have a code snippet for that?

Comment: Can you put the expected result, so it will be much easier to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely arose that at the first iteration an empty dataframe was obtained.Since the list_dictionaries[:0] slice was used. Try the code below.

```
list_dictionaries = [my_Dict, my_Dict2, my_Dict2, my_Dict2]
df_complete = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, len(list_dictionaries)):
    df = pd.json_normalize(list_dictionaries[i], sep='_')
    df_complete = pd.concat([df_complete, df])


print(df_complete.reset_index())
```

Is that what you need?

If you need two dictionaries at each iteration:

```
for i in range(0, len(list_dictionaries), 2):
    print(list_dictionaries[i:i+2])
```

If you want to connect all normalized frames in two iterations.

```
for i in range(0, len(list_dictionaries), 2):
    df1 = pd.json_normalize(list_dictionaries[i], sep='_')
    df2 = pd.json_normalize(list_dictionaries[i+1], sep='_')
    df_complete = pd.concat([df_complete, df1, df2])

df_complete = df_complete.reset_index()
print(df_complete)
```

Or in general, so as not to create unnecessary four dictionaries in 'list_dictionaries'.
It is necessary to pass in a loop a list of the necessary elements at each iteration and take indexes from them.The first iteration is the first and second[0, 1] dictionary, the second is both second[1, 1] dictionaries.

```
list_dictionaries = [my_Dict, my_Dict2]
df_complete = pd.DataFrame()
for i in [[0, 1], [1, 1]]:
    df1 = pd.json_normalize(list_dictionaries[i[0]], sep='_')
    df2 = pd.json_normalize(list_dictionaries[i[1]], sep='_')
    df_complete = pd.concat([df_complete, df1, df2])

df_complete = df_complete.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there an option to say, I want 2 elements of the list at the same time. So that the size, of the first iteration is for `i=0` `list_dictionaries = [my_Dict, my_Dict2]` and for the second iteration `i=1` = `list_dictionaries = [my_Dict2, my_Dict2]`

Comment: Updated the response. You need to get two dictionaries per iteration from the list, if I understand correctly. Is that what you need?